# NoSuchMethodError SpelParserConfiguration

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing migration spring framework.
so, every maven dependency is well in project. but when running server,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.
<init>(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
```

this error is occur.
I'm crazy about this damn error. how can i remove this evil red?

Here is my project configure:

```
...
<org.springframework-version>4.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
...

<!-- Spring -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

In first time, version is `4.3.25.RELEASE`  but  nothing going on, so down version but still error occur.

please someone help me.

Comment: Use `mvn depenency:tree` to see what gets pulled in. I suspect that Spring WS is pulling in some newer version somewhere.

Comment: I suspect spring-ws-core:2.3.1.RELEASE is pulling spring 4.0.9 version that is causing the error

Comment: Is it correctly right the version? I mean, ws-core 2.3.1 required 4.0.9 but i use 4.1.9 that more high version. then it is occur error?

Interesting.

Comment: I think it solved, but again, god damn NoSuchMethodError.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Why this damn red is not going out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was caused by duplicate dependencies in the pom.xml. I deleted duplicates, left the ones with latest versions and... problem solved!.